# BeautifulSoup doesnt return all HTML

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

so im trying to extract the value of a line of html that looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_ref_ck" value="41d875b47692bb0211ada153004a663f">
```

and to get the value im doing:

```
self.ref = soup.find("input",{"name":"_ref_ck"}).get("value")
```

and its working fine for me but i gave a friend of mine the program to beta and he is getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DI85.192\Invent Manager.py", line 262, in onOK
    self.main = GUI(None, -1, 'Inventory Manager')
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DI85.192\Invent Manager.py", line 284, in __init__
    self.inv.Login(log.user)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DI85.192\Invent Manager.py", line 34, in Login
    self.get_ref_ck()
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DI85.192\Invent Manager.py", line 43, in get_ref_ck
    self.ref = soup.find('input',{'name':'_ref_ck'}).get("value")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

which means that beautifulSoup is returning a NoneType for some reason

so i told him to send me the HTML that the request returns and it was fine then i told him to give me the soup and it only had the the top part of the page and i cant figure out why

this means the BS is returning only part of the html its recieving

my question is why or if there is an easy way i could do this with regex or something else thanks!

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML. What backend are you using with bs4?

Comment: i just said that as an example and backend?

Comment: If the original html file content is complete, maybe there are some broken tag in the html code?

Comment: bs4 has to have a parser backend http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser. which one of these are you using?

Comment: well it works on mine to i dont know why it isnt working for my friend

Comment: Is your friend using Python Idle (the one that comes with the python download)? BS4 has some problems on it... I've had random problems crop up with using BS4 on idle when it runs fine on pyscripter

Comment: i use IDLE and he isnt using and IDE he is just running it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick pyparsing-based solution walkthrough:

Import HTML parsing helpers from pyparsing

```
>>> from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, withAttribute
```

Define your desired tag expression (`makeHTMLTags` returns starting and ending tag matching expressions, you just want a starting expression, so we just take the 0'th returned value).

```
>>> inputTag = makeHTMLTags("input")[0]
```

Only want input tags having a `name` attribute = `"_ref_ck"`, use `withAttribute` to do this filtering

```
>>> inputTag.setParseAction(withAttribute(name="_ref_ck"))
```

Now define your sample input, and use the `inputTag` expression definition to search for a match.

```
>>> html = '''<input type="hidden" name="_ref_ck" value="41d875b47692bb0211ada153004a663f">'''
>>> tagdata = inputTag.searchString(html)[0]
```

Call `tagdata.dump()` to see all parsed tokens and available named results.

```
>>> print (tagdata.dump())
['input', ['type', 'hidden'], ['name', '_ref_ck'], ['value', '41d875b47692bb0211ada153004a663f'], False]
- empty: False
- name: _ref_ck
- startInput: ['input', ['type', 'hidden'], ['name', '_ref_ck'], ['value', '41d875b47692bb0211ada153004a663f'], False]
  - empty: False
  - name: _ref_ck
  - tag: input
  - type: hidden
  - value: 41d875b47692bb0211ada153004a663f
- tag: input
- type: hidden
- value: 41d875b47692bb0211ada153004a663f
```

Use `tagdata.value` to get the `value` attribute:

```
>>> print (tagdata.value)
41d875b47692bb0211ada153004a663f
```